# generate a notification after every 30 sec using periodic work manager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am developing an android app in which i want to generate notification after every 30 sec. I could use simple timer function but i need to generate notification even app is completely destroyed. Now for that purpose i used work manager api.I never used this api but work manager work only for first time.
The notification doesn't come again

this is my worker class

```
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    displayNotification();

      return Result.SUCCESS;
   }
```

this function runs in oncreate of main activity

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest dailyWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class,30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConstraints(Constraints.NONE).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance()
            .enqueue(dailyWorkRequest);
```

this is libraray i used for work manager

```
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha04"
```

Comment: The minimum `WorkManager` request interval is 15 minutes, not 30 seconds.

Comment: what if my app is completely destroyed? will work manager work after 15 min?

Comment: I am uncertain what your definition is of "completely destroyed". `WorkManager` will work even if you do not have a running process, because it uses `JobScheduler`.

Comment: completely destroyed mean app has been destroyed and not  even in the stack

Comment: That depends entirely on how the app got to that state. If the user force-stopped the app -- typically via the "Force Stop" button in Settings -- then nothing of your app will run again until the user manually launches it. On most devices, simply swiping the task out of the overview screen does not force-stop the app, and `WorkManager`/`JobScheduler` will continue to process your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your app to essentially run all the time. In that case just use a foreground `Service`, and manage notifications that way.